# Flask-login is_active won't remain changed

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

Because of the way my relational database works, instead of deleting tables from my database for deleting accounts I'd like to just deactivate them instead by changing what the is_active function returns in my User class. The problem is that my attribute 'active' in my User class won't stay False--every time I try logging in with a test account after it has been deactivated it's still able to log in just fine and through testing I've seen that current_user._get_current_object().active is True, even though I set it to false in the last session. Here is my view function:

```
@app.route('/deleteaccount', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def confirmdeletion():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        currentuser = current_user._get_current_object()
        currentuser.active = False
        flash("Account deletion successful")
        return redirect(url_for('frontpage'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form, delete=True)
```

Here is part of my models.py code:

```
class User(db.Model):
user_email = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
user_password = db.Column(db.Text)
favorites = db.relationship('Performer', secondary=favorites, backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
active = db.Column(db.Boolean)

def __init__(self, user_email, user_password):
    self.user_email = user_email
    self.user_password = user_password
    self.active = True
def __repr__(self):
    return '<User {0}>'.format(self.user_email)
def is_authenticated(self):
    return True
def is_active(self):
    return self.active
def is_anonymous(self):
    return False
def get_id(self):
    try:
        return unicode(self.user_email)
    except NameError:
        return str(self.user_email)
```

Once again, my problem is that self.active won't stay False through the /deleteaccount process. I would appreciate you help. Also, this is my first question here, so let me know if I'm missing something important in this question. Thanks.

Note: I have tried leaving out the self.active = True in the constructor, and I have tried defining it in the constructor while leaving it out of where I defined it above, and neither of those ways works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit the changes you make to the model:

```
def confirmdeletion():
    #...
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #...
        current_user.active = False
        db.session.commit()
        #...
```